# Computing $\int_{0}^{\infty} \ln(1 - e^{-\beta \hbar \omega}) \frac{3v}{2\pi^2 c_{s}^{3}} \omega^{2} \mathop{dw}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm having trouble computing the integral

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \ln(1 - e^{-\beta \hbar \omega}) \frac{3V}{2\pi^2 c_{s}^{3}} \omega^{2} \mathop{d\omega},$$

where $e$, $\hbar, \omega, \pi, c_{s}, V$ and  $\beta$ are all constants.

(side-note: this is part of an equation that's used in physics to calculate the partition function for a Debye solid).

In a book that I am reading, it is said that this integral can be evaluated by using a Taylor series expansion (I think it will be of the $\ln$ term), and then doing integration by parts once.

I have no clue how to do this, and I've tried to solve this integral for a few hours now. I think that one of my initial steps are incorrect because I'm more familiar with using integration by parts. I also tried to use this relation:

$$\ln(1 - e^{-\beta \hbar\omega}) = \ln\left(1 - \frac{1}{e^{\beta \hbar \omega}}\right) = \ln\left(\frac{e^{\beta \hbar \omega} - 1}{e^{\beta \hbar \omega}}\right) = \ln(e^{\beta\hbar\omega} - 1) - \ln(e^{\beta \hbar \omega}) = \ln(e^{\beta\hbar\omega} - 1) - \beta \hbar \omega,$$

but that also didn't get me anywhere. If anyone has any suggestions, I would much appreciate it.

EDIT: maybe writing $e^{-\beta \hbar \omega} = \cosh(x) - \sinh(x)$ can help?

Comment: $\omega=w$? $\space$

Comment: yes, you are right. it's a typo. let me fix that

Comment: And v? Is v another function of time?

Comment: No, $v$ was supposed to be volume. Let me make it capital in my original post so it's more clear. Oops, I think it was confusing because I forgot to include that in my list of constants. It is also a constant.

Comment: Oh sweet. Yea I've encountered something similar in some Materials Science texts. I'll work on this and get back to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\int_{0}^{\infty} \ln(1 - e^{-\beta \hbar \omega}) \frac{3v}{2\pi^2 c_{s}^{3}} \omega^{2} \mathop{d\omega}\\
&=&-\frac{3v}{2\pi^2 c_{s}^{3}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}e^{-n\beta \hbar \omega} \omega^{2} \mathop{d\omega}\\
&=&-\frac{3v}{2\pi^2 c_{s}^{3}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-n\beta \hbar \omega}  \omega^{2} \mathop{d\omega}\\
&=&-\frac{3v}{2\pi^2 c_{s}^{3}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\frac{2}{(\beta \hbar)^3n^3}\\
&=&-\frac{3v}{2\pi^2 c_{s}^{3}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\frac{2}{(\beta \hbar)^3n^3}\\
&=&-\frac{3v}{\pi^2 c_{s}^{3}\beta^3 \hbar^3}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^4}\\
&=&-\frac{3v}{\pi^2 c_{s}^{3}\beta^3 \hbar^3}\frac{\pi^4}{90}\\
&=&-\frac{\pi^2v}{30 c_{s}^{3}\beta^3 \hbar^3}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: how did you write the $\ln$ term as a sum? is that the taylor series?

Comment: @stackofhay42, $\ln(1-x)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1nx^n$.

Comment: how'd you evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-n \beta \hbar \omega} \omega^{2}$ ?

Comment: Integrate by parts.

Answer (score 0):

Using

$$\ln\left(1-e^{-\beta\hbar\omega}\right) = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{-\beta\hbar n\omega}}{n}$$

the integral becomes

$$I = -\frac{3v}{2\pi^2 c_s^3}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\int_0^\infty \omega^2 e^{-\beta\hbar n\omega}\,d\omega$$

Letting $\beta\hbar n\omega =: u, d\omega = \frac{du}{\beta\hbar n}$,  the integral becomes

\begin{align}
I &= -\frac{3v}{2\pi^2 c_s^3\beta^3\hbar^3}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4}\int_0^\infty u^2 e^{-u}\,du\\
&= -\frac{3v}{\pi^2 c_s^3\beta^3\hbar^3}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4}\\
&= -\frac{\pi^2 v}{30 c_s^3\beta^3\hbar^3}
\end{align}

Comment: Hi, are you sure $d\omega = u/\beta \hbar n$? I thought that's just equal to $\omega?$ Since if we use the relation $u = \beta \hbar n \omega$ and divide by $\beta \hbar n$, a different result follows

Comment: @stackofhay32 I had accidentally written $u$ instead of $du$. Everything should be fine now!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is with [Riemann Zeta Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html), and $t=\beta\hbar$
\begin{align}
\frac{3V}{2\pi^2 c_{s}^{3}}\int_{0}^{\infty} \ln(1-e^{-t\omega})\omega^2\ d\omega
&= \frac{3V}{2\pi^2 c_{s}^{3}}\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_\infty^t \dfrac{\omega e^{-\alpha\omega}}{1-e^{-\alpha\omega}} \omega^2\ d\alpha\ d\omega \\
&= \frac{3V}{2\pi^2 c_{s}^{3}}\int_\infty^t \int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\omega^3}{e^{\alpha\omega}-1}\ d\omega\ d\alpha \\
&= \frac{3V}{2\pi^2 c_{s}^{3}}\int_\infty^t \dfrac{1}{\alpha^4}\ \dfrac{\pi^4}{15}\ d\alpha \\
&= \frac{3V}{2\pi^2 c_{s}^{3}}\dfrac{\pi^4}{15} \dfrac{1}{-3t^3}\\
&= \frac{3V}{2\pi^2 c_{s}^{3}}\dfrac{\pi^4}{15} \dfrac{1}{-3\beta^3\hbar^3} 
\end{align}